# How to write custom CSS for placeholder

Tags: css, sass, placeholder

I want to customize the placeholders which comes inside the modal i.e , those comes under class styled-input.

I tried with the following CSS but it doesn't seems working.

```
.styled-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: blue !important;
}
.styled-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: blue !important;

}
.styled-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: blue !important;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: Seems to be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n5069zfn/ Please add [mcve] that we can test, css is not enough to reproduce your issue. Also please explain ***what*** is not working?